# Why are my Python packages being installed to this strange folder?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I am encountering issues with installing certain Python modules on Windows, using pip. In particular, I am using Flask, but I am encountering the error `'flask' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` in command line.

However, I am able to run my code properly with `python -m flask run` for some reason. After investigating, I figured there was a problem with my installation of Flask, so I did `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall flask` to hopefully fix the issue. I then encounter the warning message: `the script flask.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Name\Appdata\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH`.

Why would my package be installed to this location? My understanding is the default location for a package installation should be *C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib* instead. How can I fix this. It seems all my packages are being installed to this strange folder, which is giving me countless issues. I have tried force upgrading pip, and reinstalling python to no avail.

Comment: You're using the app distribution from the Microsoft Store, which is sandboxed to some extent in terms of appdata and registry locations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I realised this earlier so I downloaded the usual Python 3.8.3 from the web. How can I make sure the Microsoft Store version doesn't interfere?

Comment: Open settings -> apps -> "app execution aliases", and disable the alias for "python.exe", and any of the others that interfere. If you want to leave the store app installed, you can leave the "python3.8.exe" alias enabled. The standard installation of Python only has "python.exe". If you've uninstalled the store app, the aliases show up as "app installer", with "python[3].exe" as the executable name, and it would be best to disable them rather than keeping a "python.exe" command around that only opens the Microsoft Store.